# HTTPGet works in Java but not Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, httpclient

I am working in Android and I am having trouble with a chunk of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://9.42.68.71:8080/resources/dashboard?dashboard=rack");
    String text = null;
    try {
          HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

This chunk of code runs correctly on a different project in Java.  The problem is that when I try to use this chunk of code in Android it errors out.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
at com.example.mgen.MgenActivity.renew(MgenActivity.java:61)
at com.example.mgen.MgenActivity.refresh(MgenActivity.java:44)
... 14 more
```

I have the same imports on both projects.  Has anyone seen an issue like this or an exception like this?  I can't seem to find anything similar anywhere.

Also I have a VPN into the local 9. network and I can access it both from the android vm internet browser and my local laptop.

I have also troubleshot to find the issue on the Android version is on the line

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
```

More complete code:

```
package com.example.mgen;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MgenActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<mgenObject> listItems = new ArrayList<mgenObject>();

ArrayAdapter<mgenObject> adapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<mgenObject>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    renew();
}

// METHOD WHICH WILL HANDLE DYNAMIC INSERTION
public void refresh(View v) {

    listItems = renew();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    System.out.println("refresh worked");
}

public ArrayList<mgenObject> renewTest() {
    mgenObject object = new mgenObject("test", "test", "test");
    ArrayList<mgenObject> list = new ArrayList<mgenObject>();
    list.add(object);
    return list;

}

public ArrayList<mgenObject> renew() {
    ArrayList<mgenObject> tempList = new ArrayList<mgenObject>();
    String jsonStr = getMgenJSON();
    System.out.println(jsonStr);

    try {
        JSONArray rows = new JSONArray(jsonStr); // Parse the JSON to a
                                                    // JSONArray
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); i++) { // Loop over each each row
            JSONObject element = rows.getJSONObject(i); // Get row object
            String workflow = element.getString("workflow_state");
            String vgen = element.getString("vgen_state");
            String name = element.getString("title");

            mgenObject tempObject = new mgenObject(name, workflow, vgen);
            tempList.add(tempObject);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // JSON Parsing error
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tempList;
}

public String getMgenJSON() {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
            "http://9.42.68.71:8080/resources/dashboard?dashboard=rack");
    String text = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("testing3");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet("http://9.42.68.71:8080/resources/dashboard?dashboard=rack"));
        System.out.println("testing3.5");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("testing4");
        text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
        System.out.println("testing5");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    System.out.println(text);
    return text;
}

protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity)
        throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    InputStream in = entity.getContent();
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    int n = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        n = in.read(b);
        if (n > 0)
            out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
    }
    return out.toString();
}
}
```

Also if you cannot tell, I am trying to make this call when a button is clicked.

Comment: Your error here is in some function called renew, which is dereferencing a null pointer.  You haven't showed us code for that.  However, I can tell you this code won't work-  in Android, you can't do network IO on the main thread.  You have to do it on another thread or AsyncTask.  Also, there is no main() in Android, so I assume this is being called from somewhere.

Comment: The Null pointer is coming from the lines String jsonStr = getMgenJSON(); System.out.println(jsonStr); I don't think this is the root issue

Comment: System.out isn't the Android way to print to the log.  That would be Log.d.  So I wouldn't be shocked if out is null and is only there for compatibility.

Comment: System.out prints to LogCat, I've been using that to troubleshoot.  Removing it does not fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do network call on the main thread. Try putting your network call in the `doInBackground` of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

```
public void blah(String[] args) {
   new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            // here is for code you do before the network call. you 
            // leave it empty
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // here goes your network call
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://9.42.68.71:8080/resources/dashboard?dashboard=rack");
            String text = null;
            try {
                  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                  text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            System.out.println(text);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void res)
        {
            // here goes your UI code. i.e if you want to hide a button
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: I Updated the code, I am trying to to refresh the connection and update on a button press.  Would doInBackground work for that case?

Comment: Part of the precess is sending the text I get from the HTTPGet out to be parsed, is there a way to do this inside doInBackground?

Comment: As long as it does not need UI resources you can do it in doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

Network calls are not allowed on the main thread when working with Android. Oddly it doesn't seem like that is the issue that is being raised here. Are you working on a separate thread or an AsyncTask?

Comment: This is not on a separate thread or Async task I'll update with more code

Comment: You will need to use an async class. Use doInBackGround() for all of your network access, then use onPostExecute() to update the UI accordingly

Comment: How does this interact with a button press?  I want to either update after a certain time or at a button press calling refresh

Comment: You will need to use your onClickListener for you button to create a new instance of your AsyncTask and execute it. So when the user hits the button, the device will access the network and update the ui accordingly, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the Android code? Because this looks like plain Java. Also there are many things could go wrong in Android. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions in the manifest files. Then you need to use a background task to actually retrieve something from the network. This can be done by extending the Asynctask abstract class.

Check the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html